# How do I compare the success rates of two groups of two different sample sizes?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two drugs. Drug A and Drug B... I did a test where I gave one group Drug A and another group Drug B. For the group I have Drug A, I saw a 20% cure rate. For the group I gave Drug B,  I saw a 17% cure rate... However, there were only 1000 people in the group I have Drug A and there were 300000 people in the group I gave Drug B. Is there any method of comparing these two groups? Would I be able to test to see that if I increased the size of the first group I would then end up with the same results as the second group (due to 17% being more indicative of the entire population... Is 20% different enough from 17% where I wouldn't be worried about that, and can be confident in Drug A over Drug B?

Answer (score 1):

OK, first thing's first. Let's just do a test of proportions and see what we get

```r
N_A <- 1000
cure_A <- 200

N_B <- 300000
cure_B <- 51000

prop.test(c(cure_A, cure_B), c(N_A, N_B))
#> 
#>  2-sample test for equality of proportions with continuity correction
#> 
#> data:  c(cure_A, cure_B) out of c(N_A, N_B)
#> X-squared = 6.1436, df = 1, p-value = 0.01319
#> alternative hypothesis: two.sided
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.00467012 0.05532988
#> sample estimates:
#> prop 1 prop 2 
#>   0.20   0.17
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The p value is 0.013.  So if there truly is no difference and all our other assumptions were true and the treatment was randomly assigned, then there is a 1.3% chance we would see a difference at least as large as this.

What does this mean for you?  Well, its impossible to say what would happen if you increased the size of group A in a follow up experiment, but under the listed assumptions it would be reasonable to expect a follow up experiment to conclude that group A has a larger cure rate.